# Jmeter testing Asp.net application get timeout

Tags: asp.net, iis, jmeter

Problem:

- I testing my asp.net webapi application in my server (use IIS) and Concurrency number is set to 2000,loop count is forever,and alter several second i get `Connection timed out: connect` error

what i have tried:

1. set http connect timeout and response timeout as 200000ms in jmeter gui.
2. set requestQueueLimit to 65535 and min process to 15 in IIS manager.
3. set minWorkerThread and minIoThread to 200 and timeout to 20 miniutes in web.config file and restart my application in IIS

None of the above worked,and i found the server's cpu usage has been low ,here is the screenshot when using jmeter to test:

[cpu usage](https://blog-1257680986.cos.ap-nanjing.myqcloud.com/image-20220705104901598.png)

[jmeter screen shot](https://blog-1257680986.cos.ap-nanjing.myqcloud.com/image-20220705104951212.png)

here is the error log:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to XXX.XXX.com:80 [XXX.XXXX.com/XXXX] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:408)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:939)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:650)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1290)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
```

Comment: You can try this setting: In IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to `Manage Web Site` -> `Advanced Settings`. Under `Connection Limits` option, you should set `Connection Time-out`.

Comment: @samwu my server's connection time-out value is 120 seconds, bu jmeter get error message is about 20s after starting test

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `Maximum Concurrent Connections` and [other limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits) in your web site configuration: Advanced Settings->Limits->Maximum Concurrent Connections
2. It may be not connected with IIS at all and the timeout can happen at your website level due to incorrect database configuration or [inefficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) used. Consider re-running your test with profiler tool telemetry like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/.net/profiler/features/) or [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) - it will give you full information regarding what's going on under the hood
3. Don't run load tests using JMeter GUI, it's only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to execution you should be [running your JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)
4. [Remove all the listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean), they don't add any value and just consume valuable resources

Comment: 1. the maximun concurrent connections is 4294967295 ; 2. the Business code is very simple , i think it is not the reason 3. i tried to use  run jmeter in console mode ,the result is same. the most impotant thing is that i  found that my server network bandwidth is 5Mbps，When the stress test is performed, the network bandwidth is almost full，Could this be the real reason for timeout?

Comment: At the same time I found a very important detail, in many attempts, my request error almost always occurs around 21 seconds after the start，is 21 seconds related to the network timeout parameter of windows system? such as tcp udp?